# Python Subprocess Invalid Syntax when passing variable to function

Tags: python, subprocess, syntax-error, popen

I have a python script and want to call a subprocess from it.
The following example works completely fine:

Script1:

```
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen('python Script2.py', shell=True)
```

Script2:

```
def execute():
    print('works!')

execute()
```

However as soon as I want to pass a variable to the function, I get the following error:

```
def execute(random_variable: str):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Script1:

```
from subprocess import Popen 

p = Popen('python Script2.py', shell=True)
```

Script2:

```
def execute(random_variable: str):
    print(random_variable)

execute(random_variable='does not work')
```

Does anyone have an idea why that could be the case? Couldn't find anything about it online :(

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: When you're on a unix-like system, `python` on the command line might link to python2, which does not know type hints.

Comment: i'm using python 3.8 on a mac, with pycharm

Comment: are you running this inside virtualenv? if yes then check which python is there inside virtualenv

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct syntax for the type hint?  The examples at https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html imply you should also be defining the output type of execute. Have you tried it _without_ using a type hint at all?

Comment: no, not running in a virtualenv

Comment: actually, if I remove the type hint it seems to work fine, no Idea why.... but gonna test this first

Comment: If it works fine without the type hint, chances are good the type hint is at least contributing to the problem. Have you tried specifying the output type of execute(), as shown on the page I linked above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys, found the solution: just use 'python3' instead of 'python' if you are on mac...:

`p = Popen('python3 Script2.py', shell=True)`

Thank you for your helpfulness! :)

Answer (score 0):

Python type hint is introduced in `python3.5`.
if you run this with less than version `python3.5` then it will throw this error.

```
    def execute(random_variable: str):
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

thats why first script worked and later one failed.

Comment: alright, but actually I'm using ```python 3.8```... what could I do then to make it work?

Comment: when you create a project in pycharm it creates virtualenv, if you have a virtualenv can you make sure the correct python version?